# ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor Forms Authentication LoginURL

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, session-timeout, formsauthentication

Apologies in advance if I can't explain this very clearly.

I am using forms authentication in my MVC Razor application. I have the following in my Web.Config:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="1" />
```

Techincally this works fine. The issue I am having is that my application is split into a Header.cshtml that never changes, and then a content area that changes based on the button clicked in the header. If the session has timed out the application writes the Login.cshtml to the content area, instead of the whole page.

In my WebForms application with frames simply adding the following to the login page:

```
if (parent.frames.length > 0) {
    parent.location.href = self.document.location;
}
```

took care of the issue. Does anyone know what the equivalent of this is for MVC? I understand there is no parent to set the location of so I am kind of stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: You should do that logic in the controller so you can return a login view entirely if not logged in / session times out.

Comment: I am actually but this never gets to the controller, I think it's IIS catching that the session is timed out and redirecting to whatever is in the web config.

Comment: Change web.config to point to a different page so you can confirm/eliminate this

Comment: Duh. Yes put a different route in the web.config to an action that clears the session and returns a different partial view that redirects the whole page. Thanks!

Comment: So that helped then!?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking to do. Just couldn't figure it.